FileNotFoundError when I pickle my ML model and comment it out
I am receiving an error message while trying to load a pickled ML model for a data project. How to resolve it?
I have the correct file path and already confirmed the path "/home/jovyan/work", and loaded the pickle before.
I don't know if it is a cloud issue, but when I comment out the writing of the pickle alone, or if I comment out the writing of the pickle and the fitting of the model also... I cannot simply load the pickle for some reason. Which is the whole reason I am pickling the model to not have to fit the model every time.
These are the functions i am using:
def write_pickle(path, model_object, save_as:str): 

  with open(path + save_as + ".pickle", "wb") as to_write: 
    
    pickle.dump(model_object, to_write)

def read_pickle(path, saved_model_name:str):
  
    with open(path + saved_model_name + '.pickle', 'rb') as to_read:
        
      model = pickle.load(to_read)
    
    return model

These functions have worked with the file path and everything, but when i comment out the writing of the pickle or comment out the fitting of the ML model.... I am getting a FileNotFoundError. I don't know what the problem could be. Without me being able to figure this out, it seems that it is useless for me to even be pickling the model.

If you comment out your writing then ensure that the model has been already pickled and present in the specified directory which you can check by:
import os
print(os.listdir("home/jovyan/work"))

Also, since its a "FileNotFoundError" and if you're running this in different environment while you mentioned before that it can be a cloud issue....it can be because you might be using the relative path rather than absolute path.
